# Stuck on Power BI DAX filter (Company, Region, Market, Client)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am a new PowerBI user and after building a dashboard for my company, I am now stuck implementing RLS based on user access.

Basically, I need the RLS to look at the table 'User Access' and filter the data set (table: Country List) based on company, region, market, and client. Some users need to have access to all data in different regions or markets. (e.g. Global CEO needs access to everything, regional CEOs need access only to their regions, and each country CEO needs access to their specific country, Business Unit leaders need access to only data in their market & business unit, etc).

Given the organization size, static RLS isn't feasible.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

thanks a ton!

After much googling, the following code seemed promising, however I am now getting the error stating that 'columns cannot be converted to scalar values.'

```
VAR LoggedInUser = USERPRINCIPALNAME()
VAR RegionFilter = MAXX(FILTER('User Access', 'User Access'[Email ID] = LoggedInUser), 'User Access'[Regional Filter])
VAR MarketFilter = MAXX(FILTER('User Access', 'User Access'[Email ID] = LoggedInUser), 'User Access'[Market Filter])
VAR CompanyFilter = MAXX(FILTER('User Access', 'User Access'[Email ID] = LoggedInUser), 'User Access'[Company Filter])

RETURN
FILTER(
    'Country List',
    (
        RegionFilter = "All" || 'Country List'[Region] = RegionFilter
    ) &&
    (
        MarketFilter = "All" || 'Country List'[Market] = MarketFilter
    ) &&
    (
        AgencyFilter = "All" || 'Country List'[Company] = AgencyFilter
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dax needs to return true or false for RLS on a table. Update it to:

```
VAR LoggedInUser = USERPRINCIPALNAME()
VAR RegionFilter = MAXX(FILTER('User Access', 'User Access'[Email ID] = LoggedInUser), 'User Access'[Regional Filter])
VAR MarketFilter = MAXX(FILTER('User Access', 'User Access'[Email ID] = LoggedInUser), 'User Access'[Market Filter])
VAR CompanyFilter = MAXX(FILTER('User Access', 'User Access'[Email ID] = LoggedInUser), 'User Access'[Company Filter])

VAR resultFilter = FILTER(
  'Country List',
  ( RegionFilter = "All" || 'Country List'[Region] = RegionFilter ) &&
  ( MarketFilter = "All" || 'Country List'[Market] = MarketFilter ) &&
  ( AgencyFilter = "All" || 'Country List'[Company] = AgencyFilter )
) 

RETURN COUNTROWS(resultFilter) > 0
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?